# Typescript:Dynamically creating a json through a for loop in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

modelData:

```
0:Object
1:Object
CandidateName:"Smith John"
ControlId:0
CreatedBy:null
CreationDateTime:null
ExamId1:289
ExamName:"Drawings"
Id:1284073
```

Function

```
 public loadTestCenterData() {
            if (this.modalData!=null) {
                for (let v of this.modalData) {
                    console.log(v.ExamName);
                    this.groups = [{
                        heading: v.ExamName,
                        content: [{
                            CandidateName: v.CandidateName,
                            Id: v.Id,
                            time: '12:00',
                            Percentage: '13%',
                            Present: '50%'
                        }]
                    }];
                    this.groups.push(v);
                }

            }
            console.log(this.groups);
            }
```

From above code i am looping over modelData and creating a group array dynamically which contain heading and content json,here i am not geeting loop over groups,console showing only first object,please help me.

Comment: create a plunker

Comment: Is the `modalData` array or object?

Comment: @Hadi [object object,object ]     Object:
CandidateName:"Smith John"
ControlId:0
CreatedBy:null
CreationDateTime:null
ExamId1:289
ExamName:"Drawings"
Id:1284073

Comment: can you display what is your expect of output?

Comment: It's unclear for me why defined `content` as an array?

Comment: @Hadi just i want groups array which contain all object headings(examNames) and content is candiadate name and other.so that i can bind to accordin in angular 2

Comment: @Hadi content my accordin content for that.

Comment: sorry. please create demo.